# React native push notification not shown when app is closed

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification, freshworks

I have a react native app. I am using `react-native-push-notification` npm module for push notifications (mainly local notifications). This is working fine.

I use `OneSignal` service for remote notifications which works fine as well.

However, now I am trying to use `react-native-freshchat-sdk` (third party tool) to provide chat functionality within the app.

I have the following code

```
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token: any) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token)
        dispatch(tokenGenerated(token));
      },

      //(required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function (notification: any) {
        console.log(`**********notification received ********************* : ${JSON.stringify(notification)}`)
        Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification(notification.data, (freshchatNotification: any) => {
          if (freshchatNotification) {
            console.log(`**********freshchatNotification received *********************`)
            Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification.data);
          } else {
            console.log(`**********some other notification*********************`)
          }
        })
      },
```

Things work fine when the app is in the foreground or background. I do get remote notifications from `FreshChat` with the chat content. FreshChat uses FCM for sending notifications.
However, when the app is closed or killed, I do not get the notifications (atleast they are not shown in the tray)
When I open the chat, I can see the chat message there.
Chat remote notification looks like the following

```
{
    "foreground": false,
    "userInteraction": false,
    "id": "-1665678567",
    "data": {
        "channel_id": "748134",
        "app_id": "5787643203",
        "notif_type": "1",
        "msg_alias": "8343f922-9dfa-4fe9-9220b-61af8902e7650",
        "source": "freshchat_user",
        "body": "heelo world message",
        "timestamp": "1660956855495",
        "user_name": "Foo Bar",
        "target_user_alias": "ssd1232-75df-87f0-fsdsd",
        "conv_id": "6479825358242"
    }
}
```

I have been scratching my head to understand why I am not getting remote notifications when the app is closed. What's confusing me even more is that I get `OneSignal` remote notifications even when the app is closed. I would like to see similar behaviour with the remote notification sent by `FreshChat`

Any help pointers would be really handy. I have been stuck with these for days now and have no clue what's going wrong.
Thanks in advance